# NMOS Channel Type

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos, pmos, depletion-region

I've seen some conflicting information about the inversion channel for an NMOS device. Is NMOS n-channel or p-channel? And is the substrate n or p? I know PMOS is just the opposite for both and the channel is opposite the substrate.

Comment: NMOS is N-Channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**N-MOS** transistor looks Like this.

[image]

They are often called N-Channel MOSFET for obvious reasons.